# df.unique() on whole DataFrame based on a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a DataFrame `df` filled with rows and columns where there are duplicate Id's:

```
Index   Id   Type
0       a1   A
1       a2   A
2       b1   B
3       b3   B
4       a1   A
...
```

When I use:

```py
uniqueId = df["Id"].unique()
```

I get a list of unique IDs.

How can I apply this filtering on the whole DataFrame such that it keeps the structure but that the duplicates (based on "Id") are removed?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

It seems you need [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with parameter `subset` which specify where are test duplicates:

```
#keep first duplicate value
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Id'])
print (df)
       Id Type
Index         
0      a1    A
1      a2    A
2      b1    B
3      b3    B
```

---

```
#keep last duplicate value
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Id'], keep='last')
print (df)
       Id Type
Index         
1      a2    A
2      b1    B
3      b3    B
4      a1    A
```

---

```
#remove all duplicate values
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Id'], keep=False)
print (df)
       Id Type
Index         
1      a2    A
2      b1    B
3      b3    B
```

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible to call `duplicated()` to flag the duplicates and drop the negation of the flags.

```py
df = df[~df.duplicated(subset=['Id'])].copy()
```

[image: res1]

This is particularly useful if you want to conditionally drop duplicates, e.g. drop duplicates of a specific value, etc. For example, the following code drops duplicate `'a1'`s from column `Id` (other duplicates are not dropped).

```py
new_df = df[~df['Id'].duplicated() | df['Id'].ne('a1')].copy()
```

[image: res2]