# Filtering rows that have unique value in a column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df`:

```
id      value
1       10
2       15
1       10
1       10
2       13
3       10
3       20
```

I am trying to keep only rows that have 1 unique value in column `value` so that the result `df` looks like this:

```
id      value
1       10
1       10
1       10
```

I dropped `id = 2, 3` because it has more than 1 unique value in column `value`, `15, 13 & 10, 20` respectively.

[I read this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43184491/df-unique-on-whole-dataframe-based-on-a-column)
But this simply removes duplicates whereas I want to check if a given column - in this case column `value` has more than 1 unique value.

I tried:

```
df['uniques'] = pd.Series(df.groupby('id')['value'].nunique())
```

But this returns `nan` for every row since I am trying to fit `n` returns on `n+m` rows after grouping. I can write a function and apply it to every row but I was wondering if there is a smart quick filter that achieves my goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `transform` with groupby to align the group values to the individual rows:

```
df['nuniques'] = df.groupby('id')['value'].transform('nunique')
```

Output:

```
   id  value  nuniques
0   1     10         1
1   2     15         2
2   1     10         1
3   1     10         1
4   2     13         2
5   3     10         2
6   3     20         2
```

If you only need to filter your data, you don't need to assign the new column:

```
df[df.groupby('id')['value'].transform('nunique') == 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Let us do `filter`

```
out = df.groupby('id').filter(lambda x : x['value'].nunique()==1)
Out[6]: 
   id  value
0   1     10
2   1     10
3   1     10
```